# How to access remote sql server using sqlcmd?

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, remote-access, sqlcmd

I am trying to access remote sql server on another machine using :

```
sqlcmd -S <ip address>
```

But it gives me error -

```
command not found
```

Am I doing this wrong? Sorry but I am very new to this technology, so please let me know how i can connect to server. I have also made a user 'xyz'.
Should I have to download some client or something?
One more important thing, there is nothing install on my machine for sql server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the client tools, via the SQL Server installer, on any machine from which you connect to SQL Server.

For instance, I have the SQL Server 2012 client on this machine, with the following "shared components" of SQL Server installed:

```
Client Tools Connectivity
Client Tools Backward Compatibility
Documentation Components
Management Tools - Basic
  Management Tools - Complete
```

Clearly a minimal client wouldn't need all of these.

Also note there is a lot of cross version compatibility (eg. I can use the SQL Server 2012 tools to connect to SQL Server 2014, but clearly newer features may not be accessible).

Comment: thanks Richard for the valuable reply, but please tell me do i have to  install it if I am accessing using jdbc not sqlcmd?

Comment: As far as I am aware: Yes. You still need the underlying "SQL Native Client" (which communicates to the server), JDBC and other DB access APIs are wrappers over the database specific components.

Comment: can you suggest me any link for sql server 2008, so i can download the client and then give it a try?

Comment: @AamirSohail I always use the full Server install, no idea if there is a separate download: time to improve your search skills.

Comment: i have downloaded the tsql package and now able to access remote sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Sql Server Client Tools on "another machine" ?

Comment: demas, no please tell me what client tool should I install? and one more thing, I am trying to access via jdbc code. So do i really need client tool?

Comment: As I see you use 'sqlcmd' program. It comes with MS SQL Client Tools (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197918(v=SQL.80).aspx).

Comment: for sqlcmd we need client ok, but what about jdbc? If i am trying to access using java code, do i need this tool?

Comment: As I know you need MS JDBC driver http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx